# How to connect to DNN database?

Tags: connection, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I have a windows form application and it communicate to a web-service and it using the dotnetnuke dll only..the web service is not a DNN site its just referenced the DNN dll..

Using that webservice I need to access this dotnetnuke dll and connect to a database using dnn commands(using that dotnetnuke dll)

Please help how to do this..what are the code for connect to that databse using this dotnetnuke dll.

Comment: Never tried, but I would start by installing DNN on your development machine. Make sure your application has the same connection strings in its config file as does DNN in its web.config file.